# Throwing exception inside lambda does not work

Tags: java, lambda

I'm having bit of a problem throwing exception inside a lambda, consider the following code:

```java
public interface StoreTransactionalExecutable {
    void execute(@NotNull final StoreTransaction txn);
}
```

And a manager class:

```
public final class DatabaseManager {
  // ...
  @Override
  public void transactPersistentEntityStore(String dir, StoreTransactionalExecutable txn) {
    final PersistentEntityStore entityStore =
        getPersistentEntityStore(dir, isReadOnly);
    entityStore.executeInTransaction(txn);
  }
  // ...
}
```

When the manager class method `transactPersistentEntityStore` is accessed like this below, it works:

```
public class Service {
    databaseManager.transactPersistentEntityStore("/dbPath", txn -> {
         txn.find(); // do stuff (throws and works)
    });
}
```

However, if like this, it throws a compile-time error

```
public class Service {
    databaseManager.transactPersistentEntityStore("/dbPath", rethrow(
        transaction -> {
            StoreTransaction txn = (StoreTransaction) transaction; 
            txn.find(); // do stuff 
        }
     ));
}
```

Here's what's thrown

```
[ERROR]     method com.myproject.store.DatabaseManager.transactPersistentEntityStore(java.lang.String,jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.StoreTransactionalExecutable) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.function.Consumer<T> conforms to jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.StoreTransactionalExecutable)
[ERROR]     method com.myproject.store.DatabaseManager.<T,B>transactPersistentEntityStore(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<T>,B>,jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.StoreTransactionalExecutable) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,B
[ERROR]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

The code for the `rethrow` and `ThrowingConsumer` is this:

```
public final class Throwing {

  private Throwing() {}

  @Nonnull
  public static <T> Consumer<T> rethrow(@Nonnull final ThrowingConsumer<T> consumer) {
    return consumer;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Nonnull
  public static <E extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(@Nonnull Throwable ex) throws E {
    throw (E) ex;
  }

}
```

and

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T> extends Consumer<T>{
  @Override
  default void accept(final T e) {
    try {
      accept0(e);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      Throwing.sneakyThrow(ex);
    }
  }
  void accept0(T t) throws Throwable;
}
```

**I really wonder what could be wrong here?** Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

About the first compiler error: 
If you read the error carefully "**argument mismatch**; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.function.Consumer conforms to jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.Sto
reTransactionalExecutable"

 You'll notice a few things:

1. StoreTransactionalExecutable is not same as Consumer.
2. StoreTransactionalExecutable is not a generic type. And Consumer is.
3. StoreTransactionalExecutable doesn't extend consumer and has `execute` method not `accept`. So code inside `entityStore.executeInTransaction(txn);` calls `execute` method and not `accept`

So the compiler is complaining when you pass a Consumer object to `transactPersistentEntityStore` method.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One "sneaky" way to throw this (but with a try-catch) is to make a:

```java
public class UncheckedException extends RuntimeException {
  public UncheckedException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
  }
}
```

Then use like this:

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        databaseManager.transactPersistentEntityStore("/dbPath", txn -> {
            try {
                somethingThatThrows();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new UnchecekdServiceException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no particular reason to write all this. You can just write `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught checked", e);`, which is slightly more idiomatic to boot.